# Returning the elements in a list that are over a certain number of characters

Tags: python, string, list

I want to be able to get words that are more than 3 three letters long from a list. I am struggling with the process of doing this.

```
words = "My name is bleh, I am bleh, how are you bleh?"
```

I would like to be able to extract everything that's above 3 letters.

Comment: How did you split it into a list?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the code you've written so far, the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = []    
for word in words.split(' '):
    if len(word) >= 3:
        result.append(word)
```

When you use split you get a list containing every word of the variable 'words'. Then you iterate over it and calculate the length using len().